# Random person music library in iTunes

Tags: iphone, itunes, apple-id, music, library

I mainly use the USB connection between my MBA and iPhone 5s just to do backups. There is no music on my iPhone. Today, when I have connected my iPhone I have noticed a random music library from the person I have never met.

- macOS Sierra 10.12.4
- iOS 10.13.2

I can confirm that my iPhone has never been associated with another AppleID as I have bought it brand new.

[image]

Any ideas on what might be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means someone on the same local network as you is sharing their own library.

As it has a padlock, it means a password would be needed to listen to it.

[image]

If it wasn't password protected, you'd see a note symbol instead.

[image]

The chances of seeing 'stray' shared libraries are of course greater if you're on public wifi - you need only worry if you were connected to a supposedly private network & you don't recognise the name.

Comment: This makes sense, but let's say I am on a network at work which is shared with other colleagues, and each has its own login network login credentials. Would this music library be shown then? If everyone has different accounts on the same network.

Comment: That's precisely the scenario I'm describing. If anyone has shared their Library, then everyone on the same network can see it. Whether they can access it or not depends on whether it's private or public, password protected or not..